# Cannot open database "SchoolContext" requested by the login

Tags: c#, sql, .net-core

I work with SQL and .NET Core (DB first)

And I created a normal query

And I get an error:

> Cannot open database "SchoolContext" requested by the login. The login failed.
> Login failed for user 'LAPTOP-6HLCVNLU\sss'.

I don't understand what the error is.

I should mention that I was able to do the scaffold command.

Answer (score 0):

Your Login credentials are wrong, to access Database. E.g. username, password is wrong.
Hier a Link how to configure it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/

Comment: Need to add it to the connectionstring?
How do I find the username and password in SQL?

Comment: connection string is right. You have to ask your SQL Admin. Can you look into Database with a over Client? If it is so, you can take this credentials for the connection string